# MySQL; Different IDs in One Column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Any help is much appreciated.

I'm using this query right now.

```
SELECT t.itemID, RepID, InsRepairID
    FROM tbl_item t
        left join tbl_insiderepair i on i.itemID = t.itemID
        left join tbl_underrepair u on u.itemID = t.itemID
    where(i.itemID = t.itemID Or u.itemID = t.itemID);
```

This is the result.

```
itemID     |     RepID     |     InsRepairID
1                       3                     null
2                      null                    1
3                      null                    2
```

Now I want to make 'RepID and InsRepairID columns' (they're ID's from different tables) into ONE column.

Answer (score 1):

By Using Union You add Two Tables Show In One Column

```
Select  itemID, RepID from  tbl_item
union
SELECT   itemID,InsRepairID from tbl_insiderepair
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ifnull](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-null-function.php) sql function, like this:

```
SELECT t.itemID, IFNULL(RepID, InsRepairID) ID
FROM tbl_item t
left join tbl_insiderepair i on i.itemID = t.itemID
left join tbl_underrepair u on u.itemID = t.itemID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.itemID, COALESCE(RepID, InsRepairID)
    FROM tbl_item t
        left join tbl_insiderepair i on i.itemID = t.itemID
        left join tbl_underrepair u on u.itemID = t.itemID
    where(i.itemID = t.itemID Or u.itemID = t.itemID);
```